# Break when new variable is defined/created in browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, developer-tools

Is it possible to get chrome dev tool or firebug to break when a new variable is defined in an object? The object that I am interested is specifically the "window" object.

I get

> Uncaught ReferenceError: remoteUser is not defined

for "if(remoteUser)" in Chrome Developer Tools. The error doesn't occur everytime the page is visited, so I want to findout the line where the variable does get defined and get set to a value.

I could search the javascript files for that variable, but that route is very tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a built-in thing in Firefox: [watch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch)

One can watch even not-yet defined variable.

Usage: `window.watch("remoteUser", callback)`

Answer (score 2):

You could change it to a property and invoke `debugger;` in Chrome:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'remoteUser', {
    set: function() {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

Then just step up the call stack.